# NUnit output not shown in saved XML report

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-2.6

I am using NUnit 2.6 and have the following test case:

```
[Test]
public void TestCase()
{
    ....test case code....

// Success
Console.WriteLine("---------------->Test Passed<----------------");
}
```

After the test case is executed, the results are exported to an XML file (/xml=C:\TestResult.xml). In the resulting XML file, the console text "-->Test Passed<--" is not saved. Is there a way to show the Console.WriteLines in the XML file?

Command line:

```
"nunit-console-x86.exe" "Test.dll" /xml=C:\TestResult.xml /Domain=None /noshadow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NUnit V2 does not save the output you write in the XML result at all. NUnit 3 adds an `output` element that contains the text written by each test.

Comment: Just downloaded NUnit 3.0 and tested my code. The Output tag displays the Console.WriteLines. Guess no other way than to upgrade. Thank you.